# Download file from URL using PHP

Tags: php, download, file-put-contents

I've got loop to download 1500 XML feeds/day.
Every URL is downloaded from different server.

Currently I am using simple

`file_put_contents($filename, fopen($url, 'r'))`

I've tried also `CURL` (no success when server redirected a few times or there was some server delays or https...) and `file_get_contents` instead of `fopen` but nothing (except `fopen`) worked properly with as many different servers.

But, I've got a problem handle download without time wasting and waiting until one link ends and  another starts. I read maybe all articles here on the website and really don't know what to do.

There are situations, when:

1. server responds after 1 minute. (it'll die when my server timeout)
2. server's download speed is so low, that 250mb file is downloading 2 hours. There're some another links with 1,5Gb file downloaded under 4s without problems.

I need to handle with download the way, that in any situation it will return **true** or **false**. No error, no time wasting, no waiting for download. **Simply, if it takes, to download file, more than f.e. 5 minutes, return false and continue to another link. If it's not possible to connect or there is some error, stop action and continue to another link.** I can't find solution how to count limit for downloading or connecting.

`stream_context_create(["http"=>["timeout"=>$timeout]])` doesn't work as the links are https in 99%.

Is it possible?

Thank you for help.

Comment: _“stream_context_create(["http"=>["timeout"=>$timeout]]) doesn't work as the links are https in 99%.”_ - the HTTP wrapper is used for both HTTP and HTTPS requests.

Comment: All right, didn't know. I am using it this way and it doesn't work.
$context = stream_context_create(["http"=>["timeout"=>$timeout]]);        if(file_put_contents($filename, fopen($url, 'r', false, $context)))...

Comment: That timeout only applies when the remote server stops responding altogether, and doesn’t send _anything_ in response for the specified amount of time. For your “250MB at slow speed” problem, this isn’t a fix to begin with.

Comment: You should really use cURL here, that gives you a lot more options to fine-tune the behavior. The options CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT and CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME exist, for example.

Comment: Your best bet should be [Curl Multi Init](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php).

Comment: @CBroe Yes, so, is there any solution how to "measure" working/downloading time of file_put_contents or what's best way to do it?

Comment: Okay, two hands for CURL. Probably need to do it this way.

Comment: @Slavic, why cURL Multi Init? Is there a reason for more urls? Why not just simple curl_init? Thx.

Comment: @brook_river you said it yourself: "But, I've got a problem handle download without time wasting and waiting until one link ends and another starts."

Comment: @Slavic, yes, but it's not a loop of 1500 links on one script fire. It starts with cron.